# Executing os and subprocess in Django best practice

Tags: python, linux, django

A want to write custom Control Panel in Django for my development server and I am wondering what is the best solution for executing system calls from Django like os and subprocess on Linux?

Is there some reserved library for this purpose in Django or I should write some custom.py in my Django project where all my system calls will be placed.

Comment: Ideally, we should use something like Celery because, if any zombie process created then our main app can be affected. Check out https://digiqt.com/blog/django-best-practices-for-scalable-apps.html they have listed down such scenarios in their best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django handles only a few things related directly to the Web and the database, in modules like `views`, `urls`, `models` and a few more.

Anything else, where you implement your actual functionality, is just Python and can be placed in modules in whatever way you like, just like in any other bit of Python software. I wouldn't put systemcalls in a `custom.py`, I'd put them in a `system_calls.py`, since you already call them that. Or a library separate from the Django app.

Also, it will probably be preferable to run commands as background tasks, and only start them and see their status from the web. You should look into using Celery.

Answer (score 1):

[fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) is the way to go.  I use it mostly for deployment scripts but you can just as easily import them into python code and execute them.